# Php regexp "deleting only one charactered words" from string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, "Hello there I have a question"

I want to delete all one charactered words from this string. It must look like "Hello there have question"

I've done this:

```
$yt_tags = preg_replace('/[\w]{1}/','',$yt_tags);
```

But it deletes everything in the string.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a word-boundary (`\b`):

```
preg_replace('/\b\w\b\s*/'...
```

I added in the `\s*` to 'trim' unneeded extra whitespace (`word<space>a<space>word` would otherwise become: `word<space><space>word` instead of `word<space>word`).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly quicker but a little more complex could be:

```
$words = explode(' ', $input_string);
foreach($words as &$w)
{
    if(strlen($w) === 1)
    {
        unset($w);
    }
}
```

Note this assumes there would only be one character space between every word, which may not be the case. If you know this varies, e.g. it's coming from a form, use regex.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you should use **`\b\w\b`**.

---

Regular expression**`[\w]{1}`** matches **any word character** (letter, digit or underscore), but you want to get matches **'in a word boundary'**. These are completely different things.

Our test string: `Hello there have question`

**What is your mistake?**

> **`\w{1}`** finds any **single** word-character anywhere: `H e
>   l l o t h e r e h a v e q u e s t i o n`
>
> **`\w{2}`** finds word-character **pairs** by order:
>   `He ll th er ha ve qu es ti on` Note that odd-length words
>   missed last letter (`Hello --> He ll`)
>
> **`\w{3}`** finds word-character **triplets** anywhere:
>   `Hel the hav que sti`
>
> etc...

**And what we need?**

> **`\b...\b`** finds matches in a word boundary.
>
> **`\w`** finds a word-characters
>   (digit, letter or underscore_).
>
> **`\b\w\b`** finds one-length words. This is what we need.

HTH